# Definir valor default em uma prop do tipo Object - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Bom dia pessoal. Eu tenho um objeto chamado produto que é recebido por prop. Ele tem 41 (exatas) propriedades.
Eu preciso declarar ele com um valor default vazio pra não correr o risco de receber um 'undefined', mas eu não queria ter que listar todas as 41 propriedades e ir definindo uma por uma como null.
Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa declaração?

Segue meu código atualmente:

**componente recebendo a prop**

```html
<CardProduto :produto="getProdutoVenda(programado.armacao.idOptico)" />
```

**declaração da prop dentro do componente**

```js
props: {
  produto: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  },
}
```

Só pra contextualizar, segue o método que retorna o objeto (eu ja validei e ele retorna o objeto quando existe um produto na lista)

```js
getProdutoVenda(idOptico) {
  return this.ItensInseridos.find((f) => f.idOptico == idOptico);
},
```

Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer uma classe modelo para isso e no atributo `default` da prop retornar um novo objeto.

```js
class ObjetoEntrada {
    constructor(){
    this.field1 = null;
    //...
    this.field40 = 0;
    this.field41 = "";
    }
}
```

```js
props: {
  produto: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
    default: () => new ObjetoEntrada()
  },
}
```